# How to change the color of the each slice in piechart based on the backend response using highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using highcharts in my project and this is how my piechart looks.

[image]

This is my code

```
 this.options = {
            title : { text : 'simple chart' },
            series: [{
                data: [["success",29.9], ["Error",71.5], ["Info",106.4]],
            }],
             chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie',
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
      },
      showInLegend: true,
      colors:this.colors
    },
    
  }
        };
```

This is how I am adding the colors

```
colors = ["green", "red", "blue" , "black", "orange"]
```

Here the each slice color is applied randomly. But I need to update each slice color dynamically based on the status which I receive from the backend(eg:success). Each time I will receive 3 status from backend so based on that I need to set the color of the slice. Can anyone suggest me the way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can define slice color on a data level:

```
  series: [{
    data: [{
        name: "success",
        y: 29.9,
        color: 'green'
      },
      {
        name: "Error",
        y: 71.5,
        color: 'red'
      },
      {
        name: "Info",
        y: 106.4,
        color: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c0ur5tmg/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.data